# Memory efficient shortest path algorithm for offline Android app

Tags: android, offline, shortest-path, dijkstra, mobile-gis

Finding the shortest path in a road network requires the road network to be loaded up in memory. Using Dijkstra's algorithm, for example, it searches through all the immediate road coordinates and puts a weight on that road based on the distance and time to pass through it. This keeps on going until it reaches the destination coordinate which is when Dijkstra is able to find the shortest path.

This approach is very memory intensive since the whole road network needs to be in memory.

I would like to do some more research and look at the literature when it comes to finding the shortest path on an offline mobile app with limited memory.

Since I am quite new to this finding the appropriate literature to get acquainted with is a problem in itself.

I'm just looking for pointers.

Comment: Check out contraction hierarchies https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_hierarchies

Comment: @SeanBarbeau but this does not use the road network database. It uses 'fake' roads